# Java3D: Painting 2D HUD over a Canvas3D

Tags: java, java-3d, 3d

I'm using Java3D to render a three-dimensional scene.  I would like to overlay a two-dimensional "heads-up-display" on top of the 3d image.  How can I efficiently paint the 2d content on top of the 3d canvas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    // Create a Canvas3D using the preferred configuration
    Canvas3D canvas3d = new Canvas3D(config)
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7144426579917281131L;

        public void postRender()
        {
            this.getGraphics2D().setColor(Color.white);
            this.getGraphics2D().drawString("Heads Up Display (HUD) Works!",100,100);
            this.getGraphics2D().flush(false);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Is this same with putting buttons and lists?

Comment: I mean can you add buttons to this getgraphics2d?